# Collapsing ActionBar's spinner forces invalidation of ListFragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I develop my application using `ActionBarSherlock` and observe that when I expand then collapse `ActionBar`'s navigation Spinner the displayed `ListFragment` redraws it's `ListView`. This cause loading of photos for my list items and looks like quick flickering of images.

I would like to know if it possible not to invalidate `ListFragment`'s views after collapse of `ActionBar`'s spinner?